# two draggable on single page not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fabricjs

see below link http://liveweave.com/qddUaX

problem with two draggable on single page , last one works,
i want to drag images from two areas on both side to one common canvas,

I am trying to drag image from two draggabble area to a droppable area.
it works fine for one dropable area , when two draggble area i am having problem to drag image from one of area ..
u can see two image part at left and right .

when image is dropped from left size i get undefined message but it works fine when image is dropped from right side.

i could not figure out why it is not working .

html code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Drag and Drop</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
        <script src="http://fabricjs.com/lib/fabric.js"></script>
        <!--script src="js/Delicious_500.font.js"></script-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="wrapper">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
            <ul id="image-list">
                <li><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c3/Aurora_as_seen_by_IMAGE.PNG" class="draggable-image"></li>
            </ul>
</td><td>
            <div id="content">
                <canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="512">
                    Canvas not supported in your browser!
                </canvas>

                <div id="canvas-drop-area"></div>

                <textarea id="text-input"></textarea>

                <button id="create-text-obj">Go</button>
                <button id="save-as-image">Save as Image</button>
            </div>
</td><td>
            <ul id="image-list">

              <li><img src="http://www.gettyimages.com/CMS/Pages/ImageCollection/StaticContent/image1_%20164248809.jpg" class="draggable-image"></li>
            </ul>

</td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Delete</b></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
        </div>

        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

code of main.js

```
(function () {
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
    var canvas_el = document.getElementById('canvas');

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#create-text-obj').on('click', function () {
            var text = $('#text-input').val();
            create_text_obj(text);
        });

        $('#save-as-image').on('click', function () {
            save_canvas();
        });

        /* Bring active object to the front of the canvas */
        canvas.on('mouse:down', function (e) {
            if (!(typeof (e.target) === 'undefined')) {
                canvas.bringToFront(e.target);
            }
        });

        /* Define drag and drop zones */
        var $drop = $('#canvas-drop-area'),
            $gallery = $('td > #image-list li');

        /* Define the draggable properties */
        $gallery.draggable({
            start: function () {
                $drop.css({
                    'display': 'block'
                })
            },
            stop: function () {
                $(this).find('img').css({
                    'opacity': 0.4
                });
                $drop.css({
                    'display': 'none'
                });
            },
            revert: true
        });

        /* Define the events for droppable properties */
        $drop.droppable({
            over: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).addClass('active');
            },
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                var image = event.originalEvent.target.src,
                    loc = windowToCanvas(canvas_el, event.clientX, event.clientY);
alert(image);
                img_to_canvas(image, loc.x, loc.y);
            },
            out: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            },
            deactivate: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            }
        });
    });

    var create_text_obj = function(text) {
        var text_obj = new fabric.Text(text, {
            fontFamily: 'Delicious_500',
            left: 600,
            top: 225,
            fontSize: 80,
            textAlign: "left",
            fill: "#FF0000" // Set text color to red
        });

        canvas.add(text_obj);
    }

    var img_to_canvas = function(image, x, y) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = image;
        fabric.Image.fromURL(img.src, function (source) {
            img = source.set({
                left: 320,
                top: 256,
                angle: 0
            });
            canvas.add(img);
            canvas.renderAll();
        });
    }

    var windowToCanvas = function(canvas, x, y) {
        var bbox = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
            x: x - bbox.left * (canvas.width / bbox.width),
            y: y - bbox.top * (canvas.height / bbox.height)
        };
    }

    var save_canvas = function() {
        window.location = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    }
})();
```

Comment: Please post your code HERE, and provide good explanation... instead of just redirecting people elsewhere.

Comment: why -ve ?? may i know reasom

Comment: this is like jsfiddel , its written i forum to use jsfiddel or else for better understanding

Comment: first off the duplicate id "image-list" you are using is an unfathomable excuse...

Comment: yeah i have used td> #image-list i jquery to make it work

Comment: You definitively have the problem initializing the draggable, If both of the image are moved to same ul it is working http://liveweave.com/Ne3htY

Comment: yeah i know i want two ul on different side that is main problem how to make it work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see updated live http://liveweave.com/pCo8e2
we should capture the image when it start dragging `$draggedImage`

```
(function () {
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
    var canvas_el = document.getElementById('canvas');

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#create-text-obj').on('click', function () {
            var text = $('#text-input').val();
            create_text_obj(text);
        });

        $('#save-as-image').on('click', function () {
            save_canvas();
        });

        /* Bring active object to the front of the canvas */
        canvas.on('mouse:down', function (e) {
            if (!(typeof (e.target) === 'undefined')) {
                canvas.bringToFront(e.target);
            }
        });

        /* Define drag and drop zones */
        var $drop = $('#canvas-drop-area'),
            $gallery = $('td > #image-list li'),
            $draggedImage=null;
        /* Define the draggable properties */
        $gallery.draggable({
            start: function (e) {
              $draggedImage=event.target;
  $drop.css({
                    'display': 'block'
                });
            },
            stop: function () {
                $(this).find('img').css({
                    'opacity': 0.4
                });
                $drop.css({
                    'display': 'none'
                });
            },
            revert: true
        });

        /* Define the events for droppable properties */
        $drop.droppable({
            over: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).addClass('active');
            },
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                var image =$draggedImage&& $draggedImage.src,
                    loc = windowToCanvas(canvas_el, event.clientX, event.clientY);
                img_to_canvas(image, loc.x, loc.y);
            },
            out: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            },
            deactivate: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            }
        });
    });

    var create_text_obj = function(text) {
        var text_obj = new fabric.Text(text, {
            fontFamily: 'Delicious_500',
            left: 600,
            top: 225,
            fontSize: 80,
            textAlign: "left",
            fill: "#FF0000" // Set text color to red
        });

        canvas.add(text_obj);
    };

    var img_to_canvas = function(image, x, y) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = image;
        fabric.Image.fromURL(img.src, function (source) {
            img = source.set({
                left: 320,
                top: 256,
                angle: 0
            });
            canvas.add(img);
            canvas.renderAll();
        });
    };

    var windowToCanvas = function(canvas, x, y) {
        var bbox = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
            x: x - bbox.left * (canvas.width / bbox.width),
            y: y - bbox.top * (canvas.height / bbox.height)
        };
    };

    var save_canvas = function() {
        window.location = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    };
})();
```

Comment: Its working for me with chrome. Left image dragging doesn't work with initial post. with above code you could see both left and right were draggable to canvas area. positon needs to set as per the requirement.

Comment: i  see that drag gets stuck for chromium browser in android how to solve it

Comment: yeah i see sometimes issue that $draggedImage is null is script stop , how can i resolve it

Comment: Try with this http://liveweave.com/nzf3Y6, Change: `$draggedImage=$('img',e.target).get(0);`